# Positioning checkboxes inline in ionic

Tags: css, checkbox, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to position two checkboxes inline next to each other with their belonging 
label on the left of each checkbox.
Here is picture for better understanding: (on picture there is an e-mail checkbox which does not exist in app so just ignore it, there should be only two checkboxes)

[image]

Everything I tried so far didn't gave me wanted output so this is a code which I have now in the app.
This is in my form element:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label text-uppercase>Phone Calls</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox name="receive_calls"
      [ngModel]="(contact$ | async).receive_calls">
    </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label text-uppercase>Text Messages</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox name="receive_messages"
      [ngModel]="(contact$ | async).receive_messages">
    </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

I won't provide style code because it does not work at the moment.

Comment: You should provide your CSS to show what you've tried and to check why that code isn't working.

Comment: @Goombah I was just to add CSS styles for Your question but robban provided working example. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can replace the `<ion-item>`-elements with `<div>`'s, to get away from the extra styling you get from the `<ion-item>` elements. Also i wrapped the checkboxes in an outer `<div>`:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <div float-left class="my-checkbox">
    <ion-label text-uppercase>Phone Calls</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox name="receive_calls">
    </ion-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div float-right class="my-checkbox">
    <ion-label text-uppercase>Text Messages</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox name="receive_messages">
    </ion-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.my-checkbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**RESULT:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use  instead of

```html
 <ion-item> 
    <span>SMS &nbsp; </span>
    <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Sorry sulaiman, but this is not good solution. If you use just <span> element instead of <ion-label> your checkbox won't be selected if a user clicks on the span. Plus, you missed the point. It is supposed to place two labels + checkboxes next to each other, inline, like presented in the photo.